# How to get the .so file from mod_wsgi 4.6.4 releases

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I downloaded the zip from https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases/tag/4.6.4 but I seem to not be getting something here.  On the [README](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/master/win32/README.rst) it lists all the .so files that are available from downloading the zip but I don't see these files anywhere. Am I missing something here?  I'm just trying to get the pre-compiled module for python 2.7 but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: At the top of that readme, there's a clear statement which says that those instructions should no longer be used.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I realize that but those binaries should still be there. I feel like I'm just looking in the wrong place. The problem with using the pip method is it doesn't work for python2.

Comment: It should work. But have you considered not using Python 2? Python 3 is now almost ten years old.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Unfortunately, I have to use Python 2. I wouldn't use it if I didn't have to. Do you know where I can get those binaries?

Comment: Python 2 doesn't always work for some unknown reason related to the users compiler/system setup, or wrong choice of Apache binary. You can try with Python 2 binaries at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi. Download the ``.whl`` file and then try and ``pip install`` it, passing the path to the ``.whl`` file. You are better off using Python 3.6 though.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton What do you mean by "pip install it, passing the path to the .whl file"?

Comment: Instead of running ``pip install mod_wsgi``, replace ``mod_wsgi`` in that command with the name of the ``.whl`` file you downloaded. Eg., ``pip install .\mod_wsgi‑4.6.4+ap24vc9‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl``.